# Why does CH2F2 have such a low melting point?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

The molecule is highly polar but the melting points are way lower than non polar compounds such CCl4 or other similar non polar compound. Do even dipole dipole  have an affect on boiling point or is the size of the molecule all that matters.

Comment: Perhaps a better comparison would be to CF4, which is non-polar and has a far lower b.p and f.p. As for chlorine vs. fluorine, the more massive the halogen attached, the higher the b.p and f.p.

Comment: As you go down the family of halogens it isn't the greater mass per se that gives the higher MP and BP but the fact that the higher atomic number the bigger the atom and the more polarizable the halogen is. So none of the $\ce{CX4}$ molecules has a net dipole, but each C-X bond does have a dipole and can polarize a nearby X atom on a different $\ce{CX4}$ molecule, resulting in a net attraction.